# Why "Harry enter" and not "entered" the room?

Tags: grammaticality, sense-verbs, infinitive-constructions, nonfinite-verbs

Consider this paragraph:

> Far from wishing Harry a happy birthday, none of the Dursleys **made** any
> sign that they **had noticed** Harry ***enter*** the room, but Harry was far
> too used to this to care.

I literally don't get why it's not either *enters* the room as Harry is 3rd person singular, or *entered* as the other verbs are all in past tenses.

Comment: Please see the duplicates. It's because verbs of perception take nonfinite clauses as their complements. I noticed/saw/heard/watched him be/being more careful with this yesterday.

Comment: @tchrist I look into them, :thanks: